# Ocaml - incorrect output with lists

Tags: function, ocaml

Hello everyone I wrote a function which takes (int* float* int) list -> int* float * int

```
let least lst = 
  List.fold_left 
    (fun (a1,f1,b1) (a2,f2,b2) ->  
       if f1 < f2 then (a1,f1,b1) 
       else (a2,f2,b2)) 
    (List.hd lst) 
    lst
```

which gives me the element with the lowest float value , I've tested it and works fine.

Now I'm thinking that i can use this function make it to descending order with

```
let descending lst = 
  let rec desc lst acc = 
    match lst with
    | [] -> acc
    | (_, _, _)::t -> desc t ((least lst)::acc)
  in 
  desc lst []
```

I think that descending function should return elements in descending order but in the output some of the elements are repeated and some not included at all

can someone tell me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursion is flawed. You remove the head of the list in each step but add the least member. If the head isn't the least member then you you remove the wrong element and the least gets added multiple times.

---

This looks like insertion sort except in reverse: Extraction sort.

Given a unsorted list extract the least element and append it to the result. repeat.

```
let extract_least = function
| [] -> raise Not_found
| x::xs ->
  List.fold_left     
    (fun (least, list) x ->
      if least <= x
      then (least, x::list)
      else (x, least::list))
    (x, [])
    xs;;

let rec extract_sort = function
| [] -> []
| list ->
  let (least, list) = extract_least list
  in
    least :: extract_sort list;;
```

Comment: thanks for help, I tested your code but i think it extract_sort returns smallest element by X value from (x,float,y) shouldnt it return smallest element by float? since thats what my least function does. fo example for input (5,1.9,2) (7, 1.2 , 4) should return (7, 1.2, 4)

Comment: @vuzzie It doesn't work on tuples, only on lists and you can't have a list of ints and floats.

Comment: i meant to say list of tuples [(5,1.9,2),(7,1.2,4)]

Comment: 5 < 7 so that order is correct

Comment: yes but my original function compared only floats so 1.9>1.2 thus smallest element is (7 ,1.2 ,4)

Comment: I kinda rewrote the code, so it works just like i wanted, thanks again for the help!

Comment: well, I had to leave you something to do as homework. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this expression:

```
desc t ((least lst) :: acc)
```

It says in essence to ignore the head of the list you're looking at and to add smallest element of the list to the accumulator. So, you're ignoring some of the list elements, and (if the smallest element doesn't happen to be at the head of the list), you're adding some of the elements more than once to the accumulator.

It seems to me you don't really care which element is at the head of the list. You want to remove the least element for the recursive call, not the head.

Comment: add smallest list from the given lst which basicly is the full list on first iteration, once it finds the smallest then i run it again on tail and smalles in tail gets added , no?

Comment: The problem is that the head, which you remove, might not be the smallest element in the list. The tail then still contains the smallest element and you add it again in the next iteration.